# How to choose a view group in my android app

Tags: java, android, viewgroup

I am developing an app and have successfully added a floating action button using the library [shown here](https://gist.github.com/Jogan/9def6110edf3247825c9). The floating button displays well but when i navigate to another fragment through the navigation drawer the button still displays instead i want the button to only display in the activity i created it. I checked for those that had similar issues online and i saw comments...saying that i have to set the View by modifying this line of code found within the method show below.

```
ViewGroup root = (ViewGroup) activity.findViewById(android.R.id.content);
 root.addView(button, params);
```

Please can tell me how to achieve this, thanks in advance.

Library Method

```
 public FloatingActionButton create() {
  final FloatingActionButton button = new FloatingActionButton(activity);
  button.setFloatingActionButtonColor(this.color);
  button.setFloatingActionButtonDrawable(this.drawable);
  params.gravity = this.gravity;
  ViewGroup root = (ViewGroup) activity.findViewById(android.R.id.content);
  root.addView(button, params);
  return button;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you can access the FAB view using findViewById you can simply do:

```
button.setVisibility(VISIBILITY.GONE);
```

to hide it, that way you can set visibility back to visible when you go back to that activity.

or if you can access view called 'root' (or can access button via getActivity().findViewById for Fragments)

```
root.removeView(button);
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the `FloatingActionButton`  to be `invisible` by default in the `XML` file:

```
<ImageButton android:id="@+id/button" android:visibility="invisible"/>
```

and make it visible by using the following code in the required activity class:

```
button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```